# Where can I find a complete regex reference?

Tags: php, regex

I came across some regular expressions that I've never seen before, and I can't find any information on what they do. Here's an example:

```
/[\p{Z}\p{Cc}\p{Cf}\p{Cs}\p{Pi}\p{Pf}]/u
```

I'm looking for a full reference for regex.

P.S. I think the example provided only words in certain languages. It works in PHP but not Javascript.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a pretty good site.

Comment: Correct - PHP's implementation of REGEXP is notably more extensive than JavaScript's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete reference for PHP PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) is in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/pcre).

What you're looking at are [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), also in the PHP docs, as well as the [regular expression modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for the `u` at the end of the regex.

Comment: That is a bit inaccurate, because we are speaking only of a single Unicode character property, its ***General Category***. You cannot in PHP test for [general Unicode character properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Property_Definitions) — the way you can in can in [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) or [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) . Read the [pcresyntax](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) manpage if you want to understand the full PCRE syntax.You can’t do basic Unicode regexes in PHP per [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Basic_Unicode_Support).

Answer (score 0):

`Mastering Regular Expression 3rd` is your best choice